# "whois" output in a variable loses its formatting

Tags: shell, variables, format, whois

I have been looking through an old script I wrote which writes `whois` output to a file and then grep for certain info in that file.

I thought maybe I should change this and save the `whois` output as a variable - but when I do that, the output loses its formatting.

```
me@server:~$ echo $info_domain
 Whois Server Version 2.0 Domain names in the .com and .net domains
 can now be registered with many different
 competing registrars. Go to http://www.internic.net for detailed
 information. Server Name: EXAMPLE.COM.AU Registrar: ENETICA PTY LTD
 Whois Server: whois.enetica.com.au Referral URL:
 http://www.enetica.com.au Server Name: EXAMPLE.COM.FLORAMEIYUKWONG.COM
 IP Address: 173.203.204.123 Registrar: GODADDY.COM, LLC Whois Server:
 whois.godaddy.com Referral URL: http://registrar.godaddy.com Server
 Name: EXAMPLE.COM.RAFAELYALUFF.COM IP Address: 173.203.204.123
 [...]
```

Desired Output:

```
me@server:~$ whois example.com

Whois Server Version 2.0

Domain names in the .com and .net domains can now be registered with many different
competing registrars. Go to http://www.internic.net for detailed information.

   Server Name: EXAMPLE.COM.AU    Registrar: ENETICA PTY LTD    Whois Server: whois.enetica.com.au    Referral URL: http://www.enetica.com.au

   Server Name: EXAMPLE.COM.FLORAMEIYUKWONG.COM    IP Address:
173.203.204.123    Registrar: GODADDY.COM, LLC    Whois Server: whois.godaddy.com    Referral URL: http://registrar.godaddy.com

   Server Name: EXAMPLE.COM.RAFAELYALUFF.COM    IP Address:
173.203.204.123    Registrar: EXAMPLE.COM, LLC    Whois Server: whois.domain.com    Referral URL: http://www.example.com

.....

......
```

How can I save `whois` output to a variable without it losing its formatting?

Comment: Take a look at IFS, it may be related to this and you be able to fix it using IFS='\n';

Comment: Maybe instead of saving the whois output to a variable, you can save it to a *file* and then grep the file for what you are interested in: `whois example.com > whois.out; grep -E 'inetnum|NetRange' whois.out`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be a quoting issue. Instead of

```
echo $info_domain
```

try

```
echo "$info_domain"
```

so that the format is preserved. Technically, the double quotes prevent what shell gurus call *word splitting*.

Comment: However... $ grep -E 'inetnum|NetRange' "$info_domain"
Is returning a strange output..

Comment: @ubuntu101010101 Yes, grep treats the info_domain contents as a *file name*. You need to pass the data on stdin with `echo "$info_domain" | grep -E 'inetnum|NetRange'`